# How to integrate static code analysis[e.g. SonarQube ] with microsoft App center

Tags: xamarin.android, sonarqube, static-code-analysis, visual-studio-app-center

I have a project in Xamarin native. I am using SonarQube for static code analysis for in my local machine perfectly. Now we are using the Microsoft App Center for CICD. We have a requirement of using any static code analysis before the build is generated and give us the report and stop the build. We came across in the documentation that build scripts can be added. But I am not getting any result on how to configure static code analysis in the build scripts. Has anyone ever used build scripts for App Center with static code analysis then the help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this https://groups.google.com/g/sonarqube/c/8fV3YD32IFk?pli=1